# Azure Powershell script creates applications that don't connect properly

Tags: azure, powershell

The Azure PowerShell script below was created to automate a new application with preset roles and permissions. It does this successfully, and I'm able to replicate an application that I would have to create manually. The problem is, when I go to connect my external tool to the application, it gives a reoccurring Microsoft login page as seen below:

[image]

This page is supposed to only occur once to verify the login and then proceed to connect the tool to the Azure application. I can't find a difference between the script created application and a manual application when comparing in Azure. The problem is, the manual application connects easily while the scripted application gives the looping login page and fails. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
# Manually type in Connect-AzureAD

Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview -Scope CurrentUser
# Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantID

Install-Module Az -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
az login


#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Function to create a new Azure AD application

function Add-Application {

    param(
        [string]$AppName
    )

    $ReplyURL = Read-Host "What is your redirect URI"
    $App = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $AppName -ReplyUrls $ReplyURL
    New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $App.AppId

    Write-Output "Application Created"

    return $App
}


#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Function to add all permissions

function Add-Permission {

    param(
        $App
    )

    $targetSpGraph = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'"
    $appPermissionsRequired = @('User.Read.All','Group.Read.All','GroupMember.Read.All',`
    'GroupMember.ReadWrite.All','Directory.Read.All','AuditLog.Read.All')

    $RoleAssignmentsGraph = @()

    foreach ($AppPermission in $appPermissionsRequired) {
        $RoleAssignmentGraph = $targetSpGraph.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $AppPermission }
        $RoleAssignmentsGraph += $RoleAssignmentGraph
    }

    $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]'

    foreach ($RoleAssignmentGraph in $RoleAssignmentsGraph) {
        $resourceAccessGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess"
        $resourceAccessGraph.Id = $RoleAssignmentGraph.Id
        $resourceAccessGraph.Type = 'Role'
        $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph.Add($resourceAccessGraph)
    }

    $requiredResourceAccessGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAppId = $targetSpGraph.AppId
    $requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAccess = $ResourceAccessObjectsGraph

    $delPermissionGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182","Scope"
    $requiredResourceAccessGraph.ResourceAccess += $delPermissionGraph

    $targetSpAzure = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Windows Azure Service Management API" }
    $delPermissionAzure = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope"

    $requiredResourceAccessAzure = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $requiredResourceAccessAzure.ResourceAppId = $targetSpAzure.AppId
    $requiredResourceAccessAzure.ResourceAccess = $delPermissionAzure

    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccessGraph, $requiredResourceAccessAzure

    Write-Output "Combined Permissions Added"

    return $App
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Function to grant Admin Consent
function Add-AdminConsent {

    param(
        $App
    )
    az account get-access-token --resource https://cognitiveservices.azure.com
    az ad sp create --id $App.ObjectId
    az ad app permission admin-consent --id $App.ObjectId

    Write-Output "Admin Consent Added"

    return $App
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Function to grant the "Reader" Role

function Add-ReaderRole {

    param(
        $appName
    )
    $spId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($appName)'").ObjectId
    $subscriptionId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.id
    New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spId -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"

    Write-Output "Reader Role Added"

    return
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Create your application

$appName = Read-Host "Name your Application"
Add-Application $appName
$App = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($appName)'"
Add-Permission $App
Add-AdminConsent $App
Add-ReaderRole $appName

$PasswordCredential = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $App.ObjectId -CustomKeyIdentifier "PasswordKey"


# Output the application details
Write-Output "Azure AD Application Created:"
Write-Output " "
Write-Output "Application Name: $($App.DisplayName)"
Write-Output "Application (client) ID: $($App.AppId)"
Write-Output "Directory (tenant) ID: $((Get-AzTenant).Id)"
Write-Output "Secret (Password Credential): $($PasswordCredential.Value)"
```

Comment: The login page keeps looping and fails. You check the redirect URI in that you provided when you created the application. The redirect URI is the URL where the user is redirected after they sign in to the application. It should match the URL of your external tool. If the redirect URI is incorrect, the login page will keep looping.